# How to copy all contents of a smaller drive onto a larger one?

Tags: dd, file-copy, external-hdd

Is there some way with the command line that I can copy everything on a 256GB drive with Ntfs onto a 1TB one also with Ntfs and everything else intact?

I am thinking of a command relating to `dd` but I am not sure with the flags would be.

It is a windows operation system so the boot loader and other stuff would have to be intact.

Thx!

Comment: Do you want to copy the data onto a drive with existing files, or do you want to clone the data to an empty drive?

Comment: I think [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313081/what-tool-should-i-use-for-a-bit-by-bit-copy-of-my-hard-drive) is the answer that you need.